# how to override any .phtml or class file in magento2 using custom module?

Tags: module, overrides, magento-2.1.3, class, magento-core

Well I have an idea to create custom module in magento2 but when it comes to override code functionality I stucks.

for example I have to override this file `default.phtml` in

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order
```

to gain functionality like **product thumbnail** and **product url** in order confirmation mail so how to achieve this.

I have done this in core files which I want to do using overriding. I am confused on overriding `.phtml` file, and class file so how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

basically here block has no name in this layout `sales_email_order_renderers.xml`

So you can trick this thing

create a blank prefrence of this class  `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder`

in your module and put `default.phtml` in your modules directory

`view/frontend/template/email/items/order/default.phtml`

so by doing this , magento find this path  in your module`email/items/order/default.phtml` file instead of sales module

Hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

For override the .phtml files of any core module go through the below steps:

Create the directory in your custom theme like the below:

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme Name/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml**

And than you can put your customization code in this file for better understand go through the Magento 2 devdocs  Templates overriding [reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html)

We can do same thing for any Core module.

Hope this help.

Comment: yeah but i have to add new theme in my module which will result in a complete layout changed than that of its parent theme..i just want to use a phtml file in existing theme to override..for this i have to create a new custom theme???well does it having any alternatives so that i can override it through module...if i create a custom theme i need to set it from admin which is not a good idea so how to do it?

Comment: Are you are using the 'LUMA' theme?

Comment: no its purchased theme->SM Topshop theme
Sm/topshop

Comment: You can use the same theme, could you please let me know `vendor_name`?

Comment: Its Sm
path is /app/code/Sm/Topshop

Sm is vendor and Topshop is a theme folder inside Sm

Comment: You can override the `default.phtml` file create the directory structure like this `app/design/frontend/Sm/Topshop/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` .

Comment: ok i need to ask one more thing there is another file which is items.phtml which display out to order confirmation mail so do i need to override the same file items.phtml too...and as you have mentione dthat i have to create a folder like same in that theme..my vendor is magento_sales..so i need to override the same module

Comment: iam confused becasue here i have to override files os a vendor module Magento_sales which is not a part of theme Sm/Topshop so do i have to create a module instead that overriding Magento_Sales module.if yes than how to do this..process

Comment: Yes, you can override any `.phtml` file. Copy all the files from core module `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates` and paste in your theme folder `app/design/frontend/Sm/Topshop/Magento_Sales/` after all files will be use from your theme folder.

Comment: ok after doin customization do i need to run setup:upgrade command...

Comment: Yes, `setup:upgrade` and `cache:flush`

Comment: ok i will try and do and update you.if its resolved i will mark it as resolved.

thanks

Comment: ok iam doing it but i have one last query...in my vendor module The path is like /magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order

here magento/module-sales are seprate folders so do i have to create same structure like Sm/Topshop/magento/module-sales/rest of files or Sm/Topshop/magento_sales.. coz my structure is like that

Comment: Yes, you need to create the same structure in your theme directory. for better understand go through the reference link. [link]http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html

Comment: The answer doesn't really explain how to override the phtml using custom module, but using custom theme.